# Defer parsing of JavaScript: Unable to resolve

Tags: javascript, wordpress

We are trying to resolve the following output reported on GTmetrix: trying to defer the parsing of javascript in order to decrease the page loading time.

[image: Screenshot of GTmetrix report]

However, unable to succeed in increasing the Grade for "Defer parsing of Javascript" parameter.

We have tried the following steps on this:

1. Added the below lines of code to functions.php in /wp-content/themes/"theme"(porto) for our site; which doesn't help.

---

```
    // Custom Scripting to Move JavaScript from the Head to the Footer
function remove_head_scripts() { 
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts'); 
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9); 
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);

add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5); 
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_head_scripts' );

// END Custom Scripting to Move JavaScript
```

2. Added the below lines of code to functions.php, but doesn't help.

---

```
    // Defer Javascripts

// Defer jQuery Parsing using the HTML5 defer property

if (!(is_admin() )) {
function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
    if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
    if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
    // return "$url' defer ";
    return "$url' defer onload='";
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
}
```

3. Tried adding the 'defer="defer"' attribute manually to javascripts in header.php and footer.php, but no change.
4. Installed "Autoptimize" and "WP Deferred Javascripts" Plugins, but this affects the site's working (the dropdown menus do not appear on hover).

Please let us know if there is a way to resolve this, or if is there anything we are missing. Kindly help.

Comment: Try async attribute on script tags

Comment: If I understand you properly, then your requirement is to execute the javascripts at the end of DOM rendering. As per your code, you are expecting that WP print the scripts in footer, did you scripts get print at footer, you can check that by just viewing source of the page with (Ctrl + u)

Comment: At the top it almost looks like the same js is loaded 3 times, Why? 984.5K trippled?  Please explain that and a few lines down another similar looking thing.

Comment: @PrashanthReddy: I am unsure about the usage of "async", I mean the process of applying it here.

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar: Yes, the scripts do go to the footer; but the grade doesn't increase

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: We have an embedded a video from youtube in our website, those scripts are loaded from youtube (external javascripts I hope).

Comment: It is the same script from what I see here.  Why they would parse multiple  times is my question. Do you see that that does appear to be the crux of your issue, at least from what information is presented?  Only going by the "picture" as it is all to go on here.

Comment: @GauriChavan, Use async just like defer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding the following lines of code to /wp-includes/functions.php

```
/* Function for defer parsing of javascripts, for loading the website 
faster */

function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) 
{
   if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) 
   return $url;
   if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) 
   return $url;
   if ( strpos( $url, 'wp-custom-countdown' ) )
   return $url;
   return "$url' defer ";
}

add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
```

Comment: Earlier I was adding things to /wp-content/functions.php which was not working.